# How to print a variable using string using C++

Tags: c++, string

Suppose my code is:

```
int x = 4;
string alpha;
```

Now i want to print x using alpha, that is using

```
cout << alpha;
```

For example in this case i want 4 to be printed on screen, how to do this ?

Comment: `alpha = to_string(x);`

Comment: @MarcB: that dupe is pre c++11

Comment: @Bathsheba: do you see a c++11 tag anywhere?

Comment: c++ prior to c++11 still works in c++11, generally speaking!

Comment: C++ zealots will disapprove, but you can still do it the C way: `printf("%d", x);` (albeit directly to screen, bypassing the `alpha` and `cout` completely)

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't think we need a new question to hang C++11 answers on. The one linked as a dupe has C++11 answers, including the top voted and accepted answer. There are probably at least dozens of other duplicates too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have C++11, you can use `std::to_string(x)`.

Pre C++11 it was a little more difficult. You could use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << 4;
std::string alpha = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 4;
string alpha = to_string(x);
cout << alpha;
```

To answer the question in your comment: you can turn multiple numbers into one string by concatenating their string values:

```
alpha = to_string(x1) + to_string(x2)
```

Or with a space in between:

```
alpha = to_string(x1) + " " + to_string(x2)
```

Comment: What about if i want to print two integers simultaneously using 1 string ?

Comment: `alpha = to_string(x) + " " + to_string(y)`?

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to create your own function so then you can reuse it everywhere.

```
std::string toString (int a)
{
  std::stringstream mynewstream;
  mynewstream << a;
  return mynewstream.str();
}
```

Then if you want to do concatenate some it's easy:

```
cout << "This subject has been posted already" << toString(4000) << " times.";
```

or

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

string concat = toString(a) + toString(b);
cout << concat;
```

Will output: "12"